# Global symbol `_END_' has non-global binding

Tags: linker, makefile, ld, sigfpe

I am porting an application on Solaris 11_x86 system. When I compile it using `make, I get these errors:

```
Linking <application>...
collect2: ld terminated with signal 8 [Arithmetic Exception], core dumped
ld: warning: global symbol `_END_' has non-global binding:
(file /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so value=LOCL);
ld: warning: global symbol `_START_' has non-global binding:
(file /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so value=LOCL);
make: *** [sosd] Error 1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens when you try to link on the command line, without Make?

Comment: I tried a simple "Hello World" application from the command line. thts compiling fine..

Comment: And what happens when you try to compile and link *this application* on the command line?